# Autocomplete drop down not working

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

I want to view all the previous users whose data is there in SQLite database
but can't achieve anything after scrolling net a lot

I have tried various values for `.setThreshold()`

**Android/java code:**

```
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

        String[] previousUsers = dbHandler.getUseremails();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, previousUsers);
        mEmailView.setThreshold(1);
        mEmailView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
```

**xml code:**

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
```

**myDBHandler.java:**

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "LoginDetails.db";
    private Context context;

    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "People";
    public static final String COLUME_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUME1_NAME = "_email";
    public static final String COLUME2_NAME = "_password";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUME1_NAME + " TEXT Unique, " +COLUME2_NAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public String[] getUseremails()
    {
        String returnString[] = new String[20];
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUME1_NAME +" FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        int i=0;
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                dbString = String.format("%s", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_email")));
                returnString[i] = dbString;
                ++i;
                dbString = "";
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return returnString;
    }
```

plus the strange thing is that when I use a text watcher to fill password whenever the autofill entry matches one from the database, it fills correct password from DB. implying there is data in DB.

I want the list to drop down when we click the Textbox. I tried this by using an `onClickListener` also but could not get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, I believe, is that you are passing a **String Array** to the `ArrayAdapter` that likely has **null's** and that the ArrayAdpater takes an exception to. That is unless you have **exactly 20 rows** in the People table, some of the 20 defined elements **will not be set** and thus **be null**.

In all likelihood if you looked at the log you would likely find something similar to (*this doesn't actually crash the App so you may not have noticed it*):-

```
06-03 11:03:53.910 10422-10532/mjt.testvcsuse W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter$ArrayFilter.performFiltering(ArrayAdapter.java:480)
                                                            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

One of the solutions is to set the String Array **`returnString`** to have the correct number of elements, i.e. the number of elements would match the number of rows in the cursor.

Here's a modified version of your **`getUseremails`** method, with old code left in as comments (*P.S. I'm too lazy to include the formatting*). The real crux of the issue is resolved with **`String returnString[] = new String[c.getCount()];`**, that sets the number of array elements to the row count (note you should perhaps check to see how no rows is handled (or just take my word for it that it is hanlded OK)) :-

```
    public String[] getUseremails() {
        //String returnString[] = new String[20]; //MUST BE 20 rows else nulls
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COLUME1_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + ";";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        String returnString[] = new String[c.getCount()]; // # elements = rows
        int i = 0;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            returnString[i++] = c.getString(
                    c.getColumnIndex(COLUME1_NAME)
            );
        }
        /* OLD
        int i = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                dbString = String.format("%s", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_email")));
                returnString[i] = dbString;
                ++i;
                dbString = "";
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        */
        c.close();
        return returnString;
    }
```

Comment: i tried this too...................but its not showing the drop down list.

it is reading the values and matching it with available passwords in DB and whenever complete email matches password is displayed.

only drop down is not present

Comment: The above, as it is, works. However you say *"the list to drop down when we click the Textbox"*, That's not how `AutCompleteTextView`'s work as per *"An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically **while the user is typing**. "* https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html Perhaps you want a ListView which shows a list when you click it. I have no idea about the password, these aren't even available in the code you gave, the query selects the name only. You do mention having a `TextWatcher`, perhaps that is where the match happens.

Comment: Sorry,  said Listview above, when I meant a Spinner.